# How do I alternate tabs in Linux GNOME terminal?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, gnome

I like to open several tabs in GNOME terminal when I work. In Firefox, you can switch between tabs using Ctrl-Tab or Ctrl-Shift-Tab. How do I get the same functionality in GNOME terminal?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd> for Next Tab

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> for Previous Tab

to move tab left, try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>

Answer (score 19):

This is usually mapped to <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>PgUp</kbd> and
<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>PgDown</kbd>.

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>PgUp</kbd> and
<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>PgDown</kbd> to move tabs around.

And lastely, you can directly access the first ten tabs with
<kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> etc. ...

Answer (score 7):

**Update**: Some (newer?) versions of gnome-terminal have a `keyboard shortcuts` dialog accessible from the `Edit` menu -- eliminating the need to use `gconf-editor`.

---

You can modify the key-bindings for gnome-terminal using **gconf-editor**.

Look under: *apps/gnome-terminal/keybindings*

The man-page for gconf-editor provides some interesting comments...

> GConf-Editor is a tool used for editing the GConf configuration
>   database.  It might be useful when the proper configuration utility
>   for some software provides no way of changing some option.

and

> This  tool  allows  you to directly edit your configuration database.
>   This is not the recommended way of setting desktop
>   preferences.  Use this tool at your own risk.

---

Note: GConfig-Editor may not be installed by default.  For Debian/Ubuntu/Mint, install with:

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-editor
```

---

Example settings:

```
next_tab <Shift>Right
prev_tab <Shift>Left
```

Comment: Ubuntu-mate 18.04: getting SIGSEGV repeatedly while trying to do this with `Keyboard Shortcuts` from mate-terminal.

Comment: ...This instantaneously kills *every* terminal instance.